# Arrnage Rows Based on Duplicate Cell Values

Tags: excel

this is my scenario

i have columns A B C D and rows 1 2 3 4   i want to check for duplicate values in column C   then will like to separate rows based on duplicate values in C. for example.

before

```
  A B C D     
1 * * 8 *   
2 ! @ 1 @    
3 # # # #  
4 z z 8 x
```

after

```
  A B C D  
1 * * 8 *   
2 z z 8 x  
3 ! @ 1 @    
4 # # # #
```

Comment: @pnuts if counts of 2 values are the same, then there is a chance that the order gets changed. Isnt it?

Comment: @pnuts Do you have any examples of the order being changed?  I have read that Excel's worksheet sorting algorithm is a stable sort.  So order changing should not occur.

Comment: @GowthamShiva  I don't think that should happen if, as I have read, Excel's sorting algorithm is stable.  Any examples?

Comment: @pnuts  Ah.  Now I understand.  Thanks for clarifying.